# Shipping rates based on service custom delivery type and items total in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I just require a small help on displaying the correct shipping fees in my WordPress and woocommerce site.

I have set my shipping fees as the following:

1. Flat rate (Delivery): $10
2. Free Shipping (Free Delivery)
3. Local Pickup  (Pickup): $0

When I make an order and go onto the checkout page, it gives me the options to select from for shipping underneath the order total. I don't want the user to be able to choose out of the options.

Basically what I require is the following:

1. If the service type is Pickup, hide delivery options and only show the local pickup option
2. If the service type is delivery and the order total is $60 or below, then only show the flat rate option.
3. If the service type is delivery and the order total is above $60, then only
   show the free shipping option.

Does anybody know how to set this? Also, one thing to note, on the menu page when you add to the cart, it adds a delivery fee automatically when you open the order review container at the bottom, would be good to not set this charge until checkout if possible?

Here is the website containing the food items: https://puffpastrydelights.com/order-online/

I've tried this so far but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone');
   
function bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone( $rates ) {
    $service = $_POST['wfs_service_type']; 
    if ($service == 'pickup') {              
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:3'] );
    }else if ($service == 'delivery'){
        unset( $rates['local_pickup:2'] );
        if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:3'] )) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `service_type` is saved in a cookie. you can retrieve by `$_COOKIE`. Try the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_shipping_based_on_service_type_cart_total', 99 );
function unset_shipping_based_on_service_type_cart_total( $rates ) {

    $total   = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    $service = ( isset( $_COOKIE['service_type'] ) && $_COOKIE['service_type'] != '' ) ? $_COOKIE['service_type'] : 'pickup' ;

    if ($service == 'pickup') {              
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:3'] );
    }else if ( $service == 'delivery' && $total <= 60 ){
        unset( $rates['local_pickup:2'] );
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:3'] );
    }else if ( $service == 'delivery' && $total > 60 ){
        unset( $rates['local_pickup:2'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: dt forget to sanitize $service like this : $service = sanitize_key($_POST['wfs_service_type']);

Comment: @Bhautik Thank you, only issue is that it's not hiding the shipping options as expected

Comment: @Bhautik Ok interesting. We see some activity. It does default to pickup. So the only issue now is if I am on the checkout out page and if I decide to switch service type, the only option displays is pickup, no matter if I switch to delivery. I can confirm the cookie value for service_type is changing in the cooking, just the if statement not picking it up

Comment: I'm thinking, if we unset, do we have to reset when we switch service type options?

Comment: No, you don't have to reset.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You need first to set the posted delivery type in a WC Session variable. Then some changes in your code will be needed as follows:

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_service_type_in_a_wc_session' );
function set_service_type_in_a_wc_session() {
    // Check that user session is set
    if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
    && isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
    // Set a posted value in a WC Session variable
    if ( isset($_POST['wfs_service_type']) ) {
        WC()->session->set('service_type', sanitize_key($_POST['wfs_service_type']) );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_shipping_based_on_service_type_cart_total', 100, 2 );
function unset_shipping_based_on_service_type_cart_total( $rates, $package ) {
    // Get discounted items subtotal for the current shipping package
    $total = array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $package['contents'], 'line_total' ) );
    $service = WC()->session->get('service_type');

    if ( 'pickup' === $service ) {
        unset($rates['flat_rate:1']);
        unset($rates['free_shipping:3']);
    }
    elseif ( 'delivery' === $service ) {
        unset($rates['local_pickup:2']);

        if ( $total < 60 ){
            unset($rates['free_shipping:3']);
        } else {
            unset($rates['flat_rate:1']);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Don't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping cached data.

Comment: Thank you Loic, I am giving it a go but notice it crashes after I try to add an item to a menu

Comment: @BruceyBandit oups! sorry… I have updated My answer code and the code is working.